# Processing and displaying data from serial port - C#

Tags: c#

I'm developing a small program that receives analog data from the serial port and displays it into multiple Textboxes. 
The data is 10 bit A2D from a micro in the form of two Hex bytes and a letter to identify which A2D port it came from.

eg: 0x1A, 0x02, A

My program is receiving the data ok, and if I only display receive analog value at a time it works fine.
The problem I have is that I'm unsure how to process the incoming data when I try to receive multple A2D values.

The code below is suppose to display 3 analog values in separate text boxes, but only the first text box displays any data.  What would be the best way to go able this?

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    //Initialize a buffer to hold the received data 
    byte[] buffer = new byte[serialPort1.ReadBufferSize];

    int bytes = serialPort1.BytesToRead;

    //There is no accurate method for checking how many bytes are read 
    //unless you check the return from the Read method 
    bytesRead = serialPort1.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);

    nValue = buffer[0] + (buffer[1] << 8);
    switch1 = Convert.ToChar(buffer[2]);
    switch (switch1)
    {
        case 'A':
            DispString1 = nValue.ToString();
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(textBox0_TextChanged));
            break;
        case 'B':
            DispString2 = nValue.ToString();
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(textBox1_TextChanged));
            break;
        case 'C':
            DispString3 = nValue.ToString();
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(textBox2_TextChanged));
            break;
    }
}

private void textBox0_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox0.Text = DispString1;
}


private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = DispString2;
}

private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.Text = DispString3;
}
```

Comment: What format is the received data in?  Your comment above the `serialPort1.Read` method is **very** important, but the code does not implement anything to handle the fact that your method will almost certainly be called before the full data packet has been received.

Comment: With the debugger running I can see all the  has been received. Format is low byte, high byte, Ascii char, 0x1A0x0200x42.

Comment: The answer below from Hans Passant is correct - you'll have lots of fun trying to get the comms to work.  Once you have a full packet, you should consider changing the `Invoke` calls to `this.Invoke(new Action(()=>{textBox1.Text = nValue.ToString();}));` or something similar.

Comment: The `nValue = buffer[0] + (buffer[1] << 8);` statement could also be problematic.  Try changing it to `nValue = (((Int16)buffer[1]) << 8) + (Int16)buffer[0];` assuming nValue is an Int16.  You could also look into using `BitConverter.ToInt16` instead, although I don't remember how that handles endianism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 bytesRead = serialPort1.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
```

You blindly assume that you'll get 3 bytes, required to make the rest of the code work.  That is not how serial ports work.  You in fact usually get only 1 or 2 bytes, serial ports are very slow.  So of course your switch() statement cannot get a match.

Get ahead with:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[3];
int len = 0;
while (len < 3) {
   len += serialPort1.Read(buffer, 0, 3-len);
}
// etc..
```

Do note that you have a tricky synchronization problem.  If you call the Open() method *while* the device is sending then the first byte you receive is not necessarily the first byte of the 3 byte response.  You'll never get a proper response.  A device usually sends extra bytes to indicate the start and the end of a frame of data to help solve that problem, that however doesn't seem to be the case here.  Fixing this at the device end ought to be a strong goal.